# Laptop doesn't show any boot devices after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I decided to wipe my Windows 10 installation and to use Ubuntu from now on.

I followed a guide that instructed me to wipe all previous partitions on the HDD and then create / and swap and install. I also had to create the EFI partition.

After doing all the above process I rebooted my laptop. After POST it showed "No Bootable Devices Found".

I figures out that GRUB wasn't installed so I proceeded to manually install it. I still got the same error.

I then ran Boot-Repair to try and fix my problem. It create a [pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bqgNtMxxKf/). I still can't boot to Ubuntu.

Looking at [GParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxn10.png), all the flags seem to set correctly.

Where am I going wrong? I've spent hours with a friend trying to diagnose this but we both are clueless.

EDIT: When I plug in my bootable drive and select "Boot from another volume" I can see my HDD and boot from there into Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you set the boot mode to UEFI in firmware settings?